# SendGrid 403 Response for /v3/contactdb/recipients - Permissons needed

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

What permissions do I need or what am I doing wrong with this SendGrid API call?

I'm trying to post a new recipient ( /contactdb/recipients ) to Send Grid but keep getting a 403 response:

I get this even when calling the API from the [SendGrid Explorer](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html)

Contacts API - Recipients

- POST -> Add recipients

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "field": null,
      "message": "access forbidden"
    }
  ]
}
```

This makes me think that my API Key doesn't have enough permissions but it has Full Access.

Here is my client code as well.

```
require("dotenv").config();
const client = require("@sendgrid/client");

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const email = body.email;

  if (!process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY) {
    callback("No API Key");
  }

  client.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
  const request = {
    method: "POST",
    url: "/v3/contactdb/recipients",
    body: JSON.stringify([{ email }])
  };

  client
    .request(request)
    .then(([response, body]) => {
      // console.log(response.statusCode);
      // console.log(body);
      callback(null, response, body);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(error.response.body.errors));
      callback(error);
    });

};
```

Comment: This is super annoying because their documentation makes no mention of deprecation

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Per support:

> We have just very recently released a "New Marketing Campaigns"
>   experience and the endpoints have changed from our "Legacy Marketing
>   Campaigns".
>
> Try this endpoint:
>
> https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts
>
> I pulled it from our documentation here:
>
> ```
> https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact
> ```

Comment: Woah, thank you — the Github documentation for the Node library is out of date and never would have gotten to the bottom of this without your answer

Answer (score 1):

- Update

Previous answer does not coordinating the issue directly, sendgrid recently changed their internal api's base url, creating list of recipients which internally are static collections of Marketing Campaigns contacts. This API allows you to interact with the list objects themselves. To add contacts to a list, you must use the Contacts API.

Legacy api :

```html
/v3/contactsdb/lists
```

New functional [variant](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/lists/create-list)

```
/v3/marketing/lists
```